# How can I use Times New Roman in size 11.5?

Tags: fontsize, times

I always get the following warning:

> LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OMS/cmsy/m/n' in size <11.5> not available

Comment: Welcome! Could you please provide more details, ideally in the form of a complete small document we can compile? (A minimum working example or MWE.) The warning concerns a Computer Modern font, but not one used for text. We need to know what you're trying to do and how you are trying to do it.

Comment: If it is the main text font you want to set to 11.5pt you are out of luck with the standard classes. But `komascript`-classes "offer the feature of selection of any desired size for the main document font", cf § 4.8 of the English manual.

Comment: `cmsy` is the Computer Modern font containing the calligraphic math letters.  First of all this is not Times New Roman and second this font comes only in a few design sizes, which are 5pt, 6pt, 7pt, 8pt, 9pt, and 10pt.

Comment: I suppose you could use \scalebox from the graphicx package, but that would interfere with line breaking and hyphenation.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `cmsy` doesn't look like Times New Roman. In order to use this exact font, use the `mathptmx` package (Times font for both text and math formulae). To use any font size, you need to use Koma Script with `scrartcl` document class.

**MWE**

Input:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11.5pt]{scrartcl}
%if you want both maths and text in Times New Roman :
\usepackage{mathptmx}
%if you only want text in Times New Roman :
%\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{lipsum} %Blind text

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]
$$SE=\sqrt{\frac{1}{n-2}\left[\sum^{n}_{i=1}(y_i-\overline{y})^2-\frac{\Big[\sum^{n}_{i=1}(x_i-\overline{x})(y_i-\overline{y})\Big]^2}{\sum^{n}_{i=1}(x_i-\overline{x})^2}\right]}$$
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

Output with `mathptmx`:

[image]

Output with `times`:

[image]